# Remove scrollbar from iframe while keeping scroll ability

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll

Please review my **[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/6NCLA/embedded/result/)**...

There are two iframes embedded in images of iphones (that are hollowed out).

I am trying to achieve on the second phone what you see on the first phone, which is to hide the scroll bar, but still maintain the scrolling function.

They are both built out the same way, but the first phone allows me to scroll, and the second one does not. I'm not sure why.

**This is the CSS I'm using...**

```
.iphone5 {
    background-image: url("images/iphone5_hollow_834x380_upright.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 834px;
    width: 380px;
    margin: 20px auto 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**And the following HTML is the same for both phones (the URL is the only thing different)...**

```
<img src="http://webfro.gs/south/dev/cloud/images/iphone-5.png" style="margin: 15px auto;" />
    <div class="iphone5">
        <iframe style="width: 320px; height: 564px; margin: 134px 0 0 32px; overflow-y: hidden;" src="http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/military.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
```

If it helps to know - both of these sites are directories on the same server and primary domain.

Thoughts?

Comment: Both of your `id`s are the same. `id`s need to be unique. Try changing them to a `class` This isn't necessarily what is causing your problem, but I'm sure it's not helping.

Comment: It's changed and updated, but the only reason that was like that was for the fiddle, to show the example sites side by side so you could view them. Still hasn't changed anything though.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the source site you are framing. It is setup to be responsive and is most likely recognizing the `<iframe>` as a smaller screen and adjusting itself accordingly. Edit: After doing a little research, it appears CSS media queries do respond to `<iframes>` so that is what must be happening here.

Comment: Both sites are set up to be responsive. And they both have media queries down to 320px... I thought the same thing you did, but knowing they are both compatible down to 320px... it makes me wonder what else it could be...

Comment: Well, just because they are both responsive, doesn't mean they necessarily respond the same way. I'm assuming the media queries allow the first site to scroll, while the second is setup to utilize the navigation buttons that appear on the bottom of the iPhone "screen" I'm not very familiar with Bootstrap so I couldn't pinpoint exactly where in your source code this is happening though

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'll keep playing around with it until I get it.

Comment: No problem! Check out this question, there might be a solution for you in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403440/iframe-hide-scroll-bars-but-still-be-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-wheel?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**First**

```
 body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #F9F9F9;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Second**

```
 #tabs {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}
```

[image]